# AFTER INSERT trigger on local table inserting to Azure table fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, database-trigger

I have a really simple trigger on a SQL table in a local database. The trigger looks something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_UpdateAzureDB]
ON  [dbo].[my_local_table]
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    INSERT INTO [myazuresvr].[myazuredb].[dbo].[myazuretable]([ImageId], [PimObjectId], [Relation], [ObjectType])
    SELECT * FROM inserted
END
```

So, as you can see what I want to do is push the data that has been inserted into an Azure SQL database table. However, when I insert to the table, I get the following error:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_UpdateAzureDB, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 10]
The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "myazuresvr" reported an error. One or more arguments were reported invalid by the provider.
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure trg_UpdateAzureDB, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 10]
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "myazuresvr" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

The Server is defined as a linked server within the local server.

The really weird thing is that if I do:

```
INSERT INTO [myazuresvr].[myazuredb].[dbo].[myazuretable]([ImageId], [PimObjectId], [Relation], [ObjectType])
    SELECT * FROM [mylocaltable]
```

This completes fine. It would appear to be something to do with the fact I am inserting into an Azure table from within a trigger...

Local SQL version is 12.0.6108
Azure version shows as 12.0.2000

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is your trigger on `DELETE`, when it only references the `inserted` pseudo-ptable?

Comment: Also, using a trigger to interact with a linked server is generally a bad idea, as it can have significant performance impacts; especially when that server is in the cloud and (I assume) that the other is not, which means you could be severely bandwidth limited). What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Larnu The DELETE is only there because I haven't yet implemented that bit. As is the UPDATE. What I am trying to do is ship the data, real-time, to an Azure DB. I realise the performance implications but the number of transactions is low, and it's running as a windows service so not an issue for me.

Comment: If you want to do that, then replication would be a far better route.

Comment: Fair point, and given that the local server is already configured for replication, seems a sensible way to go. Only small kick back is that Azure obviously doesn't support pull subscriptions so the workload (such as it is) will be done from the local server. That said, the number of transactions are small so shouldn't be a big problem. If you'd like to propose that as an answer I'll mark it as such. Still doesn't explain why I can't get a simple trigger to do the insert tho...

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it's related to distributed transaction. Setting "Enable promotion of distributed transaction" flag to false should work.

[image]

Comment: But why would this allow me to do the insert as a query via the same linked server config? Surely if this was the issue it would also affect that route as well?

Comment: this is a good question. I have no idea why it let you insert directly but it fails inside the trigger statement